# How to properly format a JWT in Rust to connect to snowflake

Tags: rust, jwt, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have recently embarked in the long journey of learning Rust. Having never worked with a low level language before, I often find myself in situations where I am barley holding it together because previously a lot of the heavy lifting is abstracted away from me.

I am attempting to connect to our Snowflake instance using a JWT. The documentation for this can be found at [this page](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/authenticating).

I cannot seem to get a valid JWT to authenticate. I have confirmed my public and private key pair work by connecting in a terminal via snowSql. So the problem is almost certainly in they way I am creating the JWT.

There are a couple of questions I have that may point to the solution. I create a struct to pack in the "sub" field, I put everything in there because of the way the documentations lists the payload headers, I am unsure if this should instead be done with something like .with_issuer().

I vaguely get the idea of a fingerprint, which seems to be what is called for, but it does not look like that in the documentation either, it looks like the public key with out the ---public key begins--- stuff.

I also feel totally in the dark about the encoding_key and the encode function...

without further a due, this is what I have slapped together so far.

```
use std::time::Duration;
use reqwest;
use jwt_simple::prelude::*;
use jwt_simple::reexports::serde_json;
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc, Duration as Duration2};
use thiserror::Error;
use jsonwebtoken::{encode, Algorithm, EncodingKey, Header};


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let account_identifier = String::from("*<Account Identifier>*");
    let user = String::from("RUST");

    //create_jwt_token(&account_identifier, &user);
    let token = create_jwt_token(&account_identifier, &user);
    //dbg!(&token);
    let response = client.post( "https://*<Account Identifier>*.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/api/v2/statements")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer ".to_owned() + &token.unwrap().to_string())
        .header("X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type", "KEYPAIR_JWT")
        .header("CONTENT-TYPE", "application/json")
        .header("ACCEPT", "application/json")
        .header("User-Agent", "snowflake-rust/0.1")
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .await;

    println!("{:?}", response);


}


fn create_jwt_token(account_identifier: &str, user: &str)
                    -> Result<String, KeyPairError>
{
    let private_key = get_private_key()?;
    let public_key_fingerprint = RS256PublicKey::from_pem(&get_public_key()?)
        .map_err(KeyPairError::FingerprintGeneration)?;

    let qualified_username = format!("{}.{}", account_identifier, user);
    let issuer = format!("{}:{:?}", qualified_username, public_key_fingerprint);

    let current_time = Utc::now();


    #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
    struct MyAdditionalData {
        iss: String,
        sub: String,
        iat: i64,
        exp: i64,
    }
    let additional_data = MyAdditionalData {
        iss: issuer,
        sub: qualified_username,
        iat: current_time.timestamp(),
        exp: (current_time + Duration2::seconds(3600)).timestamp(),
    };

    let payload = Claims::with_custom_claims(additional_data,Duration::from_secs(3600).into());

    let encoding_key = EncodingKey::from_rsa_pem(private_key.as_bytes()).expect("something went wrong");
    let token = encode(&Header::new(Algorithm::RS256), &payload, &encoding_key).expect("failed to create token");

    Ok(token)
}

fn get_private_key() -> Result<String, KeyPairError> {
    let path = "./environment_variables/snowflake_private_key_path.txt";
    let private_key = std::fs::read_to_string(path)
        .map_err(|e| KeyPairError::PrivateKeyRead(e, path.into()))?;
    std::fs::read_to_string(&private_key)
        .map_err(|e| KeyPairError::PrivateKeyRead(e, private_key))
}

fn get_public_key() -> Result<String, KeyPairError> {
    let path = "./environment_variables/snowflake_public_key_path.txt";
    let public_key = std::fs::read_to_string(path)
        .map_err(|e| KeyPairError::PublicKeyRead(e, path.into()))?;
    std::fs::read_to_string(&public_key)
        .map_err(|e| KeyPairError::PublicKeyRead(e, public_key))
}

#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
pub enum KeyPairError {
    #[error("failed to read public key, path: {1}—{0}")]
    PublicKeyRead(std::io::Error, String),
    #[error("failed to read private key, path: {1}—{0}")]
    PrivateKeyRead(std::io::Error, String),
    #[error("failed to generate fingerprint from public key—{0}")]
    FingerprintGeneration(anyhow::Error),
    #[error("failed to generate key pair from private key—{0}")]
    KayPairGeneration(anyhow::Error),
}
```

The error I get from this is:

```
Ok("{\n  \"code\" : \"390144\",\n  \"message\" : \"JWT token is invalid.\"\n}")
```

Edit: Now I am struggling to get the propper JWT fingerprint.
This is what I am currently using after trying to replicate the python implementation. It "works" but outputs the wrong fingerprint.

```
let sha256_digest = digest(&SHA256, get_public_key().unwrap().as_bytes());
let public_key_fingerprint = format!("SHA256:{}", base64::encode(sha256_digest.as_ref()));
```

Comment: I have had issues with tokens in the past when it was simply encoded the wrong way, i.e. maybe the token is already base64 or urlencoded and I reapplied enciding or vice versa. It might be worth inspecting a sample valid token and comparing it to what you are posting off.

Comment: It might also be worth trying to get the Python example working just to confirm roughly what a valid JWT looks like

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid This was the right approach. I created a method to decode the JWT and found the fingerprint was malformed.
So my current predicament is the Fingerprint is not being properly created.

Comment: Excellent that you've made some progress. This site might come in handy https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue turned out to be the code I ripped from the [snowflake-connector](https://crates.io/crates/snowflake-connector) crate for creating the token was returning the fingerprint with underscores instead of slashes in the fingerprint.

I modified the fingerprint with a .replace('_',"/"); and as able to send a valid JWT.

the final result looks like so ->

```
pub(crate) fn create_token(account_identifier: &str, user: &str) -> Result<String, KeyPairError> {
let private_key = get_private_key()?;
let public_key = get_public_key()?;

let mut public_key_fingerprint = RS256PublicKey::from_pem(&public_key)
    .map_err(KeyPairError::FingerprintGeneration)?
    .sha256_thumbprint();
let padding = public_key_fingerprint.len() % 3;
for _ in 0..padding {
    public_key_fingerprint.push('=');
}
let public_key_fingerprint = public_key_fingerprint.replace('_',"/");
let qualified_username  = format!("{account_identifier}.{user}");
let issuer = format!("{qualified_username}.SHA256:{public_key_fingerprint}");
let claims = Claims::create(jwt_simple::prelude::Duration::from_secs(3_600)) //3_600 is 1 hour
    .with_issuer(issuer)
    .with_subject(qualified_username);
let key_pair = RS256KeyPair::from_pem(&private_key)
    .map_err(KeyPairError::KayPairGeneration)?;
key_pair.sign(claims)
    .map_err(KeyPairError::KayPairGeneration)
```

}